# RewriteRule for JS cache busting

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use cache busting query strings on my JavaScript/CSS, and just wondering how I can rewrite that so its part of the filename instead?

I want to rewrite: website.com/js/m/file.min.js?params to website.com/js/m/file.min.params.js instead.

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

      # Domain Redirects

      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteBase /

      RewriteRule ^/js/m/([a-zA-Z.]+).min.[0-9]+.js$ /js/m/$1.min.js [L]

      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
      RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

      #If we're here, redirect through zend:
      RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
    </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your this rule is incorrect and won't work:

```
RewriteRule ^/js/m/([a-zA-Z.]+).min.[0-9]+.js$ /js/m/$1.min.js [L]
```

**Reason:** RewriteRule matches URI without a leading slash.

Now your task:

> I want to rewrite: website.com/js/m/file.min.js?params to
>   website.com/js/m/file.min.params.js instead.

Can be handled by this rule:

```
# redirect from /js/m/file.min.js?params to /js/m/file.min.params.js
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(js/m/.+?)\.js\?([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1.%2.js? [R=301,L]

# forward from /js/m/file.min.params.js to /js/m/file.min.js?params
RewriteRule ^(js/m/.+?\.min)\.([^.]+)\.js$ $1.js?$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I added that code after the `RewriteBase /` and it redirects to the `js/m/scripts.async.min.1363759402.js`, but its still going to the last RewriteRule that redirects through index.php, as though it isn't matching on `RewriteRule ^(js/m/[^.]+\.min)\.([^.]+)\.js$ $1.js?$2 [L,QSA,NC]` ?? I.E. I would expect `js/m/scripts.async.min.1363759402.js` to load the contents of `js/m/scripts.async.min.js?1363759402` but it isn't?